# Reading text on an extJS web application with Python and Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, extjs, xpath

The HTML is as follows:
`<div id="tbtext-1555" class="x-toolbar-text x-box-item x-toolbar-item             x-toolbar-text-default" style="left: 316px; top: 6px; margin: 0px;">Displaying             Dealers 1 - 25 of 8050</div>`

I need to verify the text "Displaying Dealers" only. Using XPath, I know for a button it would be something like this: `//div[starts-with(@id, "button-")]//button[. = "Search"]`

How do I tell it to find the text? Does anyone have a site that lists the options for buttons, labels, dropdowns, etc.?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.` to refer to the text of the current node:

```
//div[contains(@class, "x-toolbar-text") and contains(normalize-space(.), "Displaying Dealers")]
```

[`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) is needed here to clean up the text from extra spaces and newlines, replace multiple spaces with a single one (which is very relevant for us in this particular case).

Comment: Thank you for responding. Unfortunately it was unable to find the text with your above answer. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: @JayWright ah, sure, spotted a mistake in the expression, fixed now. Please try.

Comment: Thank you! That's two days in a row you've made my life easier. I really appreciate your help and your time.